# Codeigniter prevent repeat data

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have a controller with 2 functions:

1. images
2. videos

I have created a `header` and `footer` template to load with my views and I want to set the css stylesheet to the user preferred setting "light" or "dark". So for example the user sets their theme to be dark I want to update the `header` view with dark.css, but I am currently repeating my code and I want to prevent that. I am having to do this twice. Once for images:

```
public function images() 
{
    //is the user logged in? if not redirect to login page
    if ( ! $this->my_auth->logged_in())
    {
      redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }

    //set the view data
    $data['title'] = 'Upload Images | My Idea Cloud';
    $data['heading'] = 'Upload Images';
    $data['attributes'] = array(
      'class' => 'dropzone',
      'id' => 'image-dropzone'                
    );

    // get users style and set the correct style sheet
    $user_data = $this->my_auth->user()->row();

    if ($user_data->style == 'light')
    {
        $data['flat_css'] = 'flat-ui-light.css';
        $data['navbar_class'] = 'navbar-default';
        $data['footer_class'] = 'bottom-menu-default';
        $data['custom_css'] = 'custom-light.css';
        $data['dropzone_css'] = 'dropzone-light.css';
    }
    elseif ($user_data->style == 'dark')
    {
        $data['flat_css'] = 'flat-ui-dark.css';
        $data['navbar_class'] = 'navbar-inverse';
        $data['footer_class'] = 'bottom-menu-inverse';
        $data['custom_css'] = 'custom-dark.css';
        $data['dropzone_css'] = 'dropzone-dark.css';
    }
    else
    {
        $data['flat_css'] = 'flat-ui-dark.css';
        $data['navbar_class'] = 'navbar-inverse';
        $data['footer_class'] = 'bottom-menu-inverse';
        $data['custom_css'] = 'custom-dark.css';
        $data['dropzone_css'] = 'dropzone-dark.css';
    }


    //load the views    
    $this->load->view('templates/frontend/front_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/frontend/front_navbar');
    $this->load->view('frontend/upload_images', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/frontend/front_footer', $data);
```

And once for the videos function

```
public function videos() 
{
    if ( ! $this->my_auth->logged_in())
    {
      redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }

    $data['title'] = 'Upload Videos| My Idea Cloud';
    $data['heading'] = 'Upload Videos';
    $data['attributes'] = array(
      'class' => 'dropzone',
      'id' => 'video-dropzone'                
    );

    // get users style and set the correct style sheet
    $user_data = $this->my_auth->user()->row();

    if ($user_data->style == 'light')
    {
        $data['flat_css'] = 'flat-ui-light.css';
        $data['navbar_class'] = 'navbar-default';
        $data['footer_class'] = 'bottom-menu-default';
        $data['custom_css'] = 'custom-light.css';
        $data['dropzone_css'] = 'dropzone-light.css';
    }
    elseif ($user_data->style == 'dark')
    {
        $data['flat_css'] = 'flat-ui-dark.css';
        $data['navbar_class'] = 'navbar-inverse';
        $data['footer_class'] = 'bottom-menu-inverse';
        $data['custom_css'] = 'custom-dark.css';
        $data['dropzone_css'] = 'dropzone-dark.css';
    }
    else
    {
        $data['flat_css'] = 'flat-ui-dark.css';
        $data['navbar_class'] = 'navbar-inverse';
        $data['footer_class'] = 'bottom-menu-inverse';
        $data['custom_css'] = 'custom-dark.css';
        $data['dropzone_css'] = 'dropzone-dark.css';
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/frontend/front_header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/frontend/front_navbar');
    $this->load->view('frontend/upload_videos', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/frontend/front_footer', $data);
```

There is more code so that is why I do not combine the two. I am only showing partial code.

Can someone guide me in the right direction on how I can consolidate my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use of `elseif` block in your code, also if you pull out common data to be passed via data, this is one attempt of minimization i can think of.

To apply this, remove `if`, `elseif` and `else` blocks from your code and put,

```
if($user_data->style == 'light')
{
    $intensity = 'light';
    $default = 'default';
}
else
{
    $intensity = 'dark';
    $default = 'inverse';
}

$data['flat_css']     = "flat-ui-{$intensity}.css";
$data['navbar_class'] = "navbar-{$default}";
$data['footer_class'] = "bottom-menu-{$default}";
$data['custom_css']   = "custom-{$intensity}.css";
$data['dropzone_css'] = "dropzone-{$intensity}.css";
```

If you want to make it more universal, create a function in same controller as,

```
function apply(&$data,$style)
{
    if($style == 'light')
    {
        $intensity = 'light';
        $default = 'default';
    }
    else
    {
        $intensity = 'dark';
        $default = 'inverse';
    }

    $data['flat_css']     = "flat-ui-{$intensity}.css";
    $data['navbar_class'] = "navbar-{$default}";
    $data['footer_class'] = "bottom-menu-{$default}";
    $data['custom_css']   = "custom-{$intensity}.css";
    $data['dropzone_css'] = "dropzone-{$intensity}.css";
}
```

and replace the first code block shown in my answer with, one single line

```
$this->apply($data,$user_data->style);
```

and you will get those five variables defined in `$data`

Comment: thanks! if I want this to apply to all my views how can I do that? I don't wan to add this every time I add a new function with views in my controllers.

Comment: awesome! i am going to try this out.

Comment: That worked! I am going to accept this as the answer. Could this be turned into a library so I don't have to create this function in every controller, but instead just load the library?

Comment: I think I answered my own question. Thanks!

Comment: or, you can copy the same function in your helper, and call by `apply($data,$user_data->style);`, that will be more preferable